# Python : A function randomly creates variables. If it already exists, it re runs the function to get new ones

Tags: python

It then sets the variables to variables in a list, which it returns.

I can only get the values returned if it doesn't run the function more than once.

Any hints as to what I may be doing wrong?

```
def randPlaceComputerSubmarine():
    count = 0
    stopPlacement = False
    print("Placing Computer Submarine")
    PC_subV1 = 0
    PC_subH1 = 0
    PC_subV2 = 0
    PC_subH2 = 0
    PC_subV3 = 0
    PC_subH3 = 0

    C_dir = randint(1,2)
    if C_dir == 1:
        C_dir = "ns"
    else:
        C_dir = "ew"


    if C_dir == 'ew':
        C_subH = randint(0,7)
        C_subV = randint(0,9)

        PC_subH1 = C_subH + 0
        PC_subH2 = C_subH + 1
        PC_subH3 = C_subH + 2

        PC_subV1 = C_subV
        PC_subV2 = C_subV
        PC_subV3 = C_subV



    if C_dir == 'ns':
        C_subH = randint(0,9)
        C_subV = randint(0,7)
        PC_subH1 = C_subH
        PC_subH2 = C_subH
        PC_subH3 = C_subH

        PC_subV1 = C_subV
        PC_subV2 = C_subV + 1
        PC_subV3 = C_subV + 2
    print("C_subV1, C_subH1 = ",PC_subV1,",",PC_subH1)
    print("C_subV2, C_subH2 = ",PC_subV2,",",PC_subH2)
    print("C_subV3, C_subH3 = ",PC_subV3,",",PC_subH3)  

    if grid[PC_subV1][PC_subH1] == "*":
        print("Ship already placed there.(1) Select another position.")
        stopPlacement = True
        C_Submarine = []
        randPlaceComputerSubmarine()

    elif grid[PC_subV2][PC_subH2] == "*":
        print("Ship already placed there.(2) Select another position.")
        stopPlacement = True
        C_Submarine = []
        randPlaceComputerSubmarine()

    elif grid[PC_subV3][PC_subH3] == "*":
        print("Ship already placed there.(3) Select another position.")
        stopPlacement = True
        C_Submairine = []
        randPlaceComputerSubmarine()


# if (grid[C_subV1][C_subH1] == "*") or (grid[C_subV2][C_subH2] == "*") or (grid[C_subV3][C_subH3] == "*"):
#       randPlaceComputerSubmarine(grid)   
#   else:
#   if stopPlacement == False:
    while (stopPlacement == False) and (count <1):
        C_Submarine = []
        count= count + 1

        C_subV1 = PC_subV1
        C_subH1 = PC_subH1
        C_subV2 = PC_subV2
        C_subH2 = PC_subH2
        C_subV3 = PC_subV3
        C_subH3 = PC_subH3

        grid[C_subV1][C_subH1] = "*"
        grid[C_subV2][C_subH2] = "*"
        grid[C_subV3][C_subH3] = "*"

        print(C_subV1)
        print(C_subH1)
        print(C_subV2)
        print(C_subH2)
        print(C_subV3)
        print(C_subH3)


        C_Submarine = [C_subV1, C_subH1, C_subV2, C_subH2, C_subV3, C_subH3]
        print (C_Submarine)
        return C_Submarine
```

Program Output

```
C_bsV1, C_bsH1 =  8 , 1 
C_bsV2, C_bsH2 =  8 , 2 
C_bsV3, C_bsH3 =  8 , 3 
C_bsV4, C_bsH4 =  8 , 4 
C_bsV5, C_bsH5 =  8 , 5 
Place Aircraft Carrier 
Place sub 
place destroyer 
Place Cruiser 
Placing Computer Aircraft Carrier 
C_acV1, C_acH1 =  6 , 4 
C_acV2, C_acH2 =  6 , 5 
C_acV3, C_acH3 =  6 , 6 
C_acV4, C_acH4 =  6 , 7 
6 
4 
6 
5 
6 
6 
6 
7 
[6, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7] 
Placing Computer Submarine 
C_subV1, C_subH1 =  6 , 7 
C_subV2, C_subH2 =  7 , 7 
C_subV3, C_subH3 =  8 , 7 
Ship already placed there.(1) Select another position. 
Placing Computer Submarine 
C_subV1, C_subH1 =  8 , 7 
C_subV2, C_subH2 =  8 , 8 
C_subV3, C_subH3 = 8 , 9 
8 
7 
8 
8 
8 
9 
[8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9] 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/Users/JLach/Desktop/Battleship10.py", line 1607, in <module>
        main(grid)   File "/Users/JLach/Desktop/Battleship10.py", line 187, in main
        getUserInput(grid)   File "/Users/JLach/Desktop/Battleship10.py", line 1211, in getUserInput
        C_subV1, C_subH1, C_subV2, C_subH2, C_subV3, C_subH3 = randPlaceComputerSubmarine() TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
    >>>
```

Comment: How is the output different from what you want?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're having?

Comment: If it has to re run the function, I get a nonetype error.

Comment: I think I fixed it by adding return before recalling the function. I've been taught though to only have one return statement at the end of the function.

Comment: In the output, it re runs place submarine and crashes when it goes to return C_submarine

Comment: "only one return statement" is a rule that is more relevant in C and Fortran than Python, so it's mostly safe to ignore. See [this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from) for more information.

Comment: That said, rather than having any recursion at all, it may be preferable to just have a `while` loop that continues until it finds a suitable placement. This method is also preferable to recursing, because it won't crash with a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error if it doesn't succeed after a hundred consecutive attempts.

Answer (score 0):

```
if grid[PC_subV1][PC_subH1] == "*":
    print("Ship already placed there.(1) Select another position.")
    stopPlacement = True
    C_Submarine = []
    randPlaceComputerSubmarine()
```

Looks like you want the result of the above `randPlaceComputerSubmarine` call to be returned by the first `randPlaceComputerSubmarine` call. If that's the case, you need to return it explicitly.

```
    return randPlaceComputerSubmarine()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you recurse you aren't returning. I suspect that if you change `randPlaceComputerSubmarine()` to `return randPlaceComputerSubmarine()` you will get correct results. When you just call the function you aren't doing anything with the results, even if the function you call returns something you won't be returning it in the original instance of the function with the current code.